# Проблемы с дублями htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

На сайте при вводе в адресную строку, например site.ru/?abrakadabra перенаправляет на главную страницу. Стоит задача сделать так, чтобы в таком случае переправлял на 404 ошибку. Пытался сделать следующим образом

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^utm_source= [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) $1? [R=301,L]
```

Не особо понимаю в этой теме, буду рад любой подсказке

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае можно задать правило, которое будет переадресовывать любой урл с непустой динамической частью, которая не начинается с `utm_source=`, на 404-ю страницу. Также, надо понимать, по какому URL находится 404-я страница, в примере ниже я предположил, что она находится в файле 404.php в корне сайта.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^utm_source= [NC]
RewriteRule .* /404.php [R=301,L]
```